Why does the lower arbitrage boundary of a European call on stock rise with time if F > S but fall if F < S?
I am reading "Option Volatility & Pricing", 2nd edition, by S. Natenberg.
On page 297, he explains the lower arbitrage boundary of European options. I don't understand the logic for what is in bold below. Any help is very much appreciated.

For futures options that are subject to stock-type settlement, the boundary is always rising because the present value is always rising towards intrinsic value. For stock options, however, the boundary may rise or fall depending on whether the forward price is greater than or less than the cash price.If the forward price is greater than the cash price (interest is greater than dividends), the lower arbitrage boundary will rise for calls and fall for puts. If the forward price is less than the cash price (interest is less than dividends), the boundary will fall for calls and rise for puts.

